# c# Interop: How to restart Selection.Find to beginning of doc?

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

Simple question that I'm not finding an answer to. My code below is in a loop and finds the first text matching "{{foo}}" in a Word doc. I then want to reset the Find so that it begins its next search at the beginning of the doc again. Currently, it picks up where after the "foo".

```
Selection sel = application.Selection;
sel.Find.ClearFormatting();
sel.Find.MatchWildcards = true;
sel.Find.Text = @"\{\{?@\}\}";
sel.Find.Forward = true;
sel.Find.Execute();
```

How do I reset the starting location of Find?

Comment: `myRange = application.ActiveDocument.Content;`

Comment: Thanks @OlivierJacot-Descombes. I implemented your suggestion of using Content with SetRange, so sel.SetRange( document.Content.Start, document.Content.End); Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: Yes, I do not have the details of the Word API in my head, but probably this is the way to go

Comment: buttonsrtoys: Have any of the contributions answered your question?

Answer (score 2):

It's always "better" to use `Range` rather than `Selection` in Word, whenever possible. You can have only one selection, but code can work with multiple ranges. In addition, the screen is quieter and execution tends to be faster. There are situations where `Selection` is necessary, but this is not one of them.

To get the `Range` of the entire document

```
Word.Range rngDoc = document.Content;
```

To "find" using the range:

```
rngDoc.Find.ClearFormatting();
rngDoc.Find.MatchWildcards = true;
rngDoc.Find.Text = @"\{\{?@\}\}";
rngDoc.Find.Forward = true;
rngDoc.Find.Wrap = Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindStop //ensure Word won't entire an infinite loop
rngDoc.Find.Execute();
```

When "find" is successful, the Range (or Selection) contains only what was found. To "reset" to start again from the beginning of the document (including the whole document):

```
rngDoc = document.Content;
```

And (what people ask more frequently) to continue searching from just beyond the "found" term to the end of the document:

```
object oCollapseEnd = Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd;
rngDoc.Collapse(ref oCollapseEnd); //go just beyond what was found
rngDoc.End = document.Content.End;
```

Answer (score 0):

In VBA we'd use:

```
Selection.HomeKey Word.WdUnits.wdStory
```

So, in your C# code would that convert to?

```
Sel.HomeKey(Word.wdUnits.wdStory);
```

Comment: Thanks @Rich Michaels. I couldn't find the equivalent of wdStory in C#. There's equiv for wdLine and wdParagraph, but didn't see Story?

Comment: Can you use an enumeration value? It would be 6 for wdStory. A line is 5, paragraph 4, section is 8.

Answer (score 0):

.Find.Execute always resets the range to the found range. Accordingly, you need to either re-set it to the entire document (as per Olivier's comment) or use the C# equivalent of .Wrap = wdFindContinue (VBA) to instruct Word to continue searching from the top after getting to the end of the document.